# How to Integrate an App as part of another Android App

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I have a small game like unity app for android, I want to distribute it among other android developers so that they could integrate it as part of their app. 
ie basically an intent from an app should launch my app's activity and on backpressed it has to return to previous activity just like normal activities work.

**Most Importantly I dont want to share my code with other developers**, and want to charge others for using my game. I goggled and came across terms like dependencies, libraries, plugins etc, also I got some suggestions to do it like game updates. ie when user wants to launch my activity ask him to download the portion from online.

Can anyone suggest me the best options to do this, and suggest some documentations/ tutorials or any kind of reference to do the same

Answer (score 1):

You can compile your scripts to DLL's and other Unity developers can use them like normal scripts.

http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UsingDLL.html

Comment: But how can other native developers integrate it into their project.??

Comment: Is there any way to integrate dynamically linked library to android studio projects..???

Comment: The solution I proposed works fine for Unity developers but I'm not sure how to integrate it with native Android development..